# Can I just let Sapper's preload function just await a promise without it needing to return the result of that promise?

Tags: svelte, sapper, svelte-3

I understand the thing with having a `preload()` function in a `<script context="module">` tag, and that whatever that function returns gets passed to the component as an external property, provided you wrote `export let whatever` in your component.

Now I'm using firestore together with rxfire, both serverside *and* clientside. So I can just do an `import { posts } from '../store'` and then `posts` will literally be a store that will continuously update itself whenever it gets new snapshots from firebase's firestore.

In the [Svelte tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/module-exports) I've noticed that any variable you declare in a `<script context="module">` will also be available to your html template, just like when you had declared it in the normal `<script>` tag.

So then my train of thought was, I don't actually *need* the `preload()` function to return any properties to inject in my component. Since the `posts` variable is already available to the html template. The only thing I really need to do in `preload()` is to make sure it waits until the first data snapshot from firestore has arrived. So that would've looked something like this:

```html
<script context="module">
  import { posts } from '../store'
  import { first } from 'rxjs/operators'

  export async function preload() {
    const result = await posts.pipe(first()).toPromise()
    console.log(result) // this is just here to check if the results did indeed arrive
  }
</script>

<h1>Recent posts</h1>

<ul>
  {#each $posts as post}
    <li>
      <a href="/blog/{post.slug}" rel="prefetch">
        {post.title}
      </a>
    </li>
  {/each}
</ul>
```

When I run this code I can see in my terminal that the posts data is indeed correctly printed from `console.log`, so I *know* the data arrived. But for some reason I don't understand, it doesn't work, because the template still ends up with a store that doesn't contain the first snapshot of data yet. So the SSR html that the server sends to the browser ends up with an empty list.

I thought maybe it had to do with the fact that it's a store and not a raw data-value. So I simplified my code to see if that was the problem.

```html
<script context="module">
  import { wait } from '../utils'
  import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

  const blabla = writable('first value')

  export async function preload() {
    await wait(1000) // simulate a delay, like we would have when retrieving data from firestore
    blabla.set('second value')
  }
</script>

<h1>{$blabla}</h1>
```

That then the SSR html code *does* contain the text `second value`. So I don't know what the problem is.

Anyone knows what gives?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to fix it by replacing rxjs and rxfire with my own code that wraps firestore live snapshots in a svelte store.
So there must just be some weird incompatibility rxjs that messed things up.